# Definition List With Single Item

Tags: html, css, forms, list, semantic-markup

I have a form with several label / input tag pairs. Within the same form I have one pair that is informational only, that is it is a name / value pair. The value is calculated and is for the user's convenience, it is not to be submitted with the form. I want to present this info to the user in a way that looks consistent with the label / input pairs. ie I want the name part of the name value pair to look like the labels, but a label in this scenario would not be semantically correct since it is not referring to an input tag. The value part I don't need to look like an input since it is not an input, but I want the spacing to be the same as with the inputs. A definition list would be perfect for this type of thing, but my concern is that this is not a list per se, it is only one item.

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834977/is-it-semantically-correct-in-html-to-markup-a-list-with-only-a-single-list-item), but there was no conclusive / accepted answer, plus it referred to unordered lists. I think a definition list is a slightly different beast since it is probably more common to need a single term / definition pair than it would be to have a single item in a list. Maybe there is a tag for what I want, like a single term / definition pair type thing and I am just having a brain fart.

**Edit: **

Some code to illustrate (surrounding form elements for context)

```
<div>
    <label for="PaymentDate">Payment Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="PaymentDate" name="PaymentDate">
</div>
<dl>
    <dt>Key</dt>
    <dd>Value</dd>
</dl>
<div>
    <label for="Reference">Reference</label>
    <input type="text" id="Reference" name="Reference">
</div>
```

OR

```
<div>
    <label for="PaymentDate">Payment Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="PaymentDate" name="PaymentDate">
</div>
<div>
   <span class="key">Key</span>
   <span class="value">Value</span>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="Reference">Reference</label>
    <input type="text" id="Reference" name="Reference">
</div>
```

So my question is: What are the pros or cons of each approach from a semantic perspective? The downside with spans for me is that in this scenario I would likely have to add a class to the span to format it since I am already using spans for error messages, whereas I could just make a rule in my css file to format the definition list since the only purpose I would use a definition list for within a form would be for the scenario described above.

Comment: Questions like “is it semantically correct...” are opinion-based, in addition to being practically useless. Consider presenting your problem with writing HTML code or styling it, as a real question, illustrated by sample markup and accompanied with descriptions of how it might not be suitable, on specific practical grounds.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I edited the question to add some HTML code and rephrased the question, but when it comes down to it just about every question on semantic markup on Stack Overflow comes down to "best practices" or whether something is "semantically correct" whether it is phrased that way or not.

Comment: If you want to associate a key to a value, a `dl` is suitable, even if it contains only one item. But I can't tell what "Amount" and "Value" are supposed to be - are those the actual strings in your form, or are they placeholders for the label and the value that's being calculated?

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you. Amount is akin to a form label, ie a Name, whereas Value is a placeholder. Value is calculated server side so rather than show something like <%= Value %> which is language specific I just put in the word Value.